# RatingBar colour appears White after upgrading Google Play Services 7.5.0

Tags: android, android-widget, google-play-services, ratingbar

My Application was running quite good until I upgraded to 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'. I was using the RatingBar in an activity which was working fine. But after upgrading, the Ratingbar color appears white. Even i tried to change the color using code and layout, but the color appears white. But when i touch the rating bar, some green coloured ratingbar appears.

**Code:**

```
<RatingBar
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/ratingBar"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
    android:stepSize="0.5"
    android:progressBackgroundTint="#ff048ec4"
    android:progressTint="#ff048ec4"
    android:progressBackgroundTintMode="multiply"
    android:progressTintMode="multiply" />
```

The problem is only with the versions lower than Lollipop. There is no issue in Lollipop, but in Kitkat & lower versions the color appears white.

Does anyone know the solution for this? 
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

**`For API >= 21`**

```
Drawable progress = ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
DrawableCompat.setTint(progress, Color.YELLOW);
```

**`For API < 21`**

```
RatingBar ratingBar = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
LayerDrawable stars = (LayerDrawable) ratingBar.getProgressDrawable();
stars.getDrawable(2).setColorFilter(Color.YELLOW,PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
```